# Evaluation of polynomials at tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, tensor-products, tensors

> Let $S,T$ be $R$-algebras, $f \in S[X]$ a polynomial. In my notes it says you can easily lift $f$ to a polynomial $f'$ in $(S \otimes T)[X]$. But I have no idea what $f'(s \otimes t)$ is.

My guess is $f'(s \otimes t)=(f(s),f(t))$ but I am not sure at all. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be that $f'(s\otimes t) = (f(s),f(t))$ because on one hand $f$ isn't necessarily defined on $T$ (as a polynomial function), while on the other hand $(f(s),f(t))$ isn't an element of $S \otimes T$.

Now, note that there is a natural map $S \to S \otimes T$, namely $s \mapsto s \otimes 1$. Thus if $f \in S[X]$ is
$$
f(X) = a_n X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dotsc + a_0
$$
you can lift it to
$$
f'(X) = (a_n \otimes 1) X^n + (a_{n-1} \otimes 1) X^{n-1} + \dotsc + a_0 \otimes 1
$$
and you can evaluate it at $s \otimes t \in S \otimes T$ just like any other polynomial, remembering that $(s_1 \otimes t_1) (s_2 \otimes t_2) = (s_1s_2) \otimes (t_1t_2)$, i.e.
$$
f'(s \otimes t) = a_n s^n \otimes t^n + a_{n-1} s^{n-1} \otimes t^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_0 \otimes 1
$$

**Note:** Here I'm assuming that all your rings are commutative and with unit.